# How can I push an image that is floated right to the bottom of the browser window?

Tags: html, css

I have an image in my website that is defined with the following CSS:

```
#settings_big{
    border: none !important;
    margin: auto 0 0 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
    float: right;
}
```

Because of the float the image obviously sits on the right side of the content. The top margin causes the image to sit right beneath the lowest hanging element in the content. This looks OK, but I would really prefer that the image sit as low as possible in the browser window to somewhat frame the content. I've seen multiple examples that use fixed positioning to achieve this, and this would work, however my content has a max and min width of 960px; using a fixed position of

```
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
```

causes the image to get pushed far right outside of the content to the edge of the browser window. Is it possible to push the image to the bottom of the browser window while keeping the

```
float: right;
```

positioning? I would rather not use JavaScript or jQuery but it is an option I suppose. Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you want the bottom edge of the image to be at the bottom of the view port, and the right edge of the image to coincide with the right edge of the web page (which has 960px width and centered(?))?

Comment: Adding some HTML would help...

Comment: @MarcAudet Yes that is correct. And yes the web page is centered. I could do this with jQuery but I would rather not. Also the HTML wouldn't help much, which is why I didn't include any. It is just a simple image inside of a centered div. Let me know if you still want it.

Comment: A better solution would involve knowing the height of the image or the width.  Is this possible in your design?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following might be close to what you need.

Assuming that your page layout vaguely looks like the following HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <p>some words...</p>
    <div class="slot">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200">
    </div>
</div>
```

apply the following CSS:

```css
.wrapper {
    width: 600px;
    height: 600px; /* for demo only, not critical... */
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
.slot {
    text-align: right;
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: 0;
    margin-left: -301px;
    width: 600px;
    border: 1px dotted blue;
}
.wrapper img {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

See demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/6Xnxj/

If you don't know the width of the image (or you don't want to specify it), 
create a wrapper that matches the width of the parent element and apply `position: fixed` to it.

The image can then be either floated or text-aligned to the right within the fixed block.

The fixed block can then be positioned to the left and bottom, and using margin-left
to keep it centered.

Answer (score 1):

New answer:

```
<div class="container contentCont">
  <div id="content"></div>
</div>
<div class="container imageCont">
  <div id="image"></div>
</div>
```

With CSS:

```
.container {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #ccc;
}

.contentCont {
  min-height: 600px;
}

.imageCont {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#image {
  float: right;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 4px solid red;
}
```

Does it right as in this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WYX7H/1/

Comment: This won't work, the box offsets for `position: fixed` are always with respect to the view port, not the parent element.

Comment: I'll be damned, you're right. How about this for a solution: http://jsfiddle.net/WYX7H/1/

Comment: Your updated version works, in fact, similar to whatI posted, we both came up with the same idea, some of the details are slightly different but the concept is good!

Comment: Why don't you post your HTML and CSS, you have a working solution.